# How can I make a simple table row with numbers using .appendChild?

Tags: javascript, onclick, appendchild

I'm a beginning programmer and I wondered if someone could help me.

I want to get a table with a row and 7 numbers in table data & making the function react.  I tried this but it doesn't work, and I've been looking for some time at it now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function maaktable () {
    alert("Hey!");

    var tabdata
        = tabrow.appendChild(document.createElement("td").innerText
        = amount[i];
    var tabrow = tablestart.appendChild(document.createElement("tr");
    var tablestart = document.createElement("table");

    tablestart;
    tabrow;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tabdata;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="maaktable()">Begin</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is it doesn't even alert.  What can i do to make this work?

Comment: Did you check for syntax errors? Because while semi-colons are optional, their omission (given the linebreaks in your shown code) should generate quite a few errors.

Comment: This bit doesn't look right: `var tabdata = tabrow.appendChild(document.createElement("td").innerText = amount[i];`

Comment: You're not appending the elements you're creating. Just by _calling_ the variable won't do that. ie: `tablestart;`

Comment: You're also using a variable before it's declared. Check your browser console (F12) for errors.

Comment: I checked for syntax errors now:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; tablegenerate%20appendchild.html:11
2Uncaught ReferenceError: maaktable is not defined
tablegenerate%20appendchild.html:29

Comment: It looks like you're doing things in the reversed order.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added line breaks on the double assignment, to keep the code from having a horizontal scroll bar...believing that it [did not introduce *additional* errors](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26302879/revisions) that weren't there to begin with.  If that's not true, then someone is going to have to re-explain semicolon insertion to me, because I don't believe the line breaks cause any additional problems.

Comment: Thank you all for your reactions, i have learned alot from it. :)

Comment: @NickdeBoom The best way to thank people is to check an answer as "accepted", which closes the question from the "needs an answer" list... and gives you 2 points also.

Comment: Thank you HostileFork! Now i know that for the future. :)

Comment: @NickdeBoom another tip: when you use the `@` sign to address people it generates notifications.  If you don't use it, they may miss your follow-up comments.  Welcome and good luck in programming, be sure to [read as much of the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as you can to try and avoid getting pounced on...which can make it a not-fun-time, despite the large amount of knowledge and fast answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well not sure if this is the intended result but your code does look a little off 
this should at least get the alert to show and hopefully get you on the right track

```
function maaktable () {
    alert("Hey!");

    var tablestart = document.createElement("table");
    var tabrow = tablestart.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //tabdata;
         tabrow.appendChild(document.createElement("td").innerText(amount[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a missing `)` in your first `appendChild`.